# What is the easiest way to connect to Memgraph using Node.js?

Tags: memgraphdb

I want to test the creation of an application that uses Node.js and Memgraph. What is the fastest and easiest way for me to test this type of setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/). Here are the exact steps:

1. Create a new directory for your application, `/MyApp` and position yourself in it.
2. Create a `package.json` file using `npm init`
3. Install Express.js using `npm install express --save` and the Bolt driver using `npm install neo4j-driver --save` in the /MyApp directory. Both packages will be added to the dependencies list.

To make the actual program, create a `program.js` file with the following code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
var neo4j = require("neo4j-driver");

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://localhost:7687");
  const session = driver.session();

  try {
    const result = await session.writeTransaction((tx) =>
      tx.run(
        'CREATE (a:Greeting) SET a.message = $message RETURN "Node " + id(a) + ": " + a.message',
        {
          message: "Hello, World!",
        }
      )
    );

    const singleRecord = result.records[0];
    const greeting = singleRecord.get(0);

    console.log(greeting);
  } finally {
    await session.close();
  }

  // on application exit:
  await driver.close();
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Once you save the file, you can run your program using `node program.js`.

For additional details [check the official Memgraph documentation](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/connect-to-memgraph/drivers/nodejs).